# Remove recipient from MailMessage when mailbox is unavailable

Tags: c#, email, smtp

I'm using the `SmtpClient` class of `System.Net.Mail`. I would like to remove invalid recipients from the `MailMessage.To` field when the SmtpClient rejects an email address. Is this possible? This is the code I have, but it throws on `smtpClient.Send(message)` if `message.To` contains an email that the client cannot send to (it works just fine when all emails are valid).

```
    public void SendEmail(Machine machine)
    {
        var message = new MailMessage();
        var smtpClient = new SmtpClient(smtpServer);

        message.From = new MailAddress(emailSender);

        foreach (var recipient in machine.Recipients)
        {
            message.To.Add(recipient);
        }

        message.Subject = string.Format(emailSubject, machine.Name, machine.Address);
        message.Body = ""; // body here

        message.Priority = MailPriority.High;

        smtpClient.Send(message);
    }
```

Error:
Transaction failed. The server response was: 5.7.1 < #email-removed# >: Relay access denied

Answer (score 0):

When one of recipients is invalid Send method throw SmtpFailedRecipientsException. You should look at the example in msdn for SmtpFailedRecipientsException
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpfailedrecipientsexception(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The documentation only suggests a retry after five seconds. This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: SmtpFailedRecipientsException have property FailedRecipient and InnerExceptions.
In Examples is loop in which try again send message, but you don't must retry try sending message, you can get only ex.InnerExceptions[i].FailedRecipient or ex.FailedRecipient. I've never used it, but I think it may be answer to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

For a 5.7.1 response you actually get a plain SmtpException instead of SmtpFailedRecipientException/SmtpFailedRecipientsException - see the .NET Framework source code [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/net/System/Net/mail/SmtpCommands.cs,596) -, so you'll have to check the Message property of the exception to identify the corresponding address (e.g. use String.Contains), if included.